The Remotion composition is not rendering the component
I've been trying to render the video player component, but unfortunately, I'm not observing any output in the dev tools console. Even the expected 'Player' message isn't appearing in dev tool. Could you offer guidance on what might be causing this issue? I've checked my code thoroughly, but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.
  <Composition
          id="MyVideoComposition"
          component={VideoPlayer}
          durationInFrames={300}
          fps={30}
          width={1920}
          height={1080}
        />

// here is my VideoPlayer component file

import { AbsoluteFill, Series } from "remotion";
import { strToSeconds } from "../../../../utils/helper";
import { PlayAudio } from "./playAudio";
import { PlayVideo } from "./playVideo";
 
 

export function VideoPlayer( PlayerType) {
     
const clips = [
    {
      video_url: '',
      thumpnail_url:'',
      audio_url:'',
      text:'',
      videoToStart: '00:00:00:000',
      videoToEnd: '00:00:06:000',
      audioLength: '00:00:11:208',
      videoEditType: 'loop',
      animationIn: 'fadeIn',
      animationOut: '',
      animationDuration: 0.5
    },
  ]

    console.log("Player")

    return (
        <AbsoluteFill>
            <Series>
            {clips.map((clip, index) => {
                const videoStartSeconds = strToSeconds(clip.videoToStart);
                const videoEndSeconds = strToSeconds(clip.videoToEnd);
                const videoDurationInSeconds = videoEndSeconds - videoStartSeconds;
                const durationInFrames = videoDurationInSeconds;

                return (
                    <Series.Sequence key={index} durationInFrames={durationInFrames}>
                        <PlayVideo
                            src={clip.video_url}
                            initialDuration={videoStartSeconds} // Start time in seconds
                            totalDuration={videoDurationInSeconds} // Duration in seconds
                        
                        />
                        <PlayAudio
                            src={clip.audio_url}
                        />
                    </Series.Sequence>
                );
            })}
            </Series>

        </AbsoluteFill>
    );
}


Even the following code also not rendering the player.
  <Composition
          id="MyVideoComposition"
          component={()=>  <AbsoluteFill>
            <Video src={"some url here..."} />
          </AbsoluteFill>}
          durationInFrames={300}
          fps={30}
          width={1920}
          height={1080}
        />

Please help me with this. I'm unsure why this is happening.
